# How to find out who did not handle an event

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, eventaggregator

We have a rather large application built with C#/WPF/Prism. The application has a few static modules and an unknown number of dynamically loaded modules.

My area of influence is with the static modules and the shell.

I am asked to implement a feature that will restart the shell, but only after querying all currently open modules whether restarting is allowed. If at least one module says it's not allowed (example: still unsaved changes), the restart is postponed.

Now the shell and the modules communicate via the `EventAggregator`. Which means I can publish an event and then see if any of the subscribers denied or allowed the restart.

This works great for all modules I could change. However, I cannot change the dynamic modules (different teams, different source control).

One requirement was that if any module *does not* support this new feature, it should be treated as having denied that restart.

**The obvious problem is, how do I find out, that somebody *did not subscribe* to the event?**

Although all viewmodels implement our `IViewModel` interface, I see no way of finding out how many viewmodels currently exist (so I could at least see if all allowed it, or if some answers are simply missing).

I could probably find out, how many *modules* support it, but even then that says nothing about how many viewmodels are currently open/existing/used by views.

Is there a way to find out if an active viewmodel is not supporting this without changing said viewmodel?

Comment: When prism is loading modules you [could update some counter](https://jinishbhardwaj.wordpress.com/2011/12/25/prism-controlling-module-loading-and-initialization/) in the shell to keep track of number of modules loaded. You should also have number of modules who accepted or denied restart. Summing them up should be equal to that counter variable you have. Am I missing something?

Comment: @3615 That is my current workaround, to have an Attribute that modules can have so I can find out how many *modules* don't support it. But a module may have multiple views and multiple viewmodels, so having X modules, I might as well get X-Y or even X+Y replies... and if it's X+Y I still don't know if there's views and viewmodels floating around that did not answer :(

Comment: In addition, it would be good if I could ignore a module that's not supporting it, if it has no open view/viewmodels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At any given moment you can look at IRegionManager.Regions to find all existing regions.  Each IRegion in the collection has IRegion.ActiveViews which gives the list of all currently active views in the region.  Then each view (which is an object) may be inspected whether it has some attribute attached or implement some interface.  Then, if the view is FrameworkElement, you may also inspect its DataContext.

If you found a view without attribute/interface, the view does not support restarting.  If a view has attribute/interface, you query that interface.

If you create additional (scoped) region managers, you will need to keep track of them.  You maintain a list of active region managers, initially containing only the region manager attached to the shell.  While inspecting a view, if the view is a FrameworkElement and has region manager attached to it and that attached region manager is not in the list, you add it to the list and examine the views controlled by that region manager using the same algorithm.

Comment: Wow, thank you, that sounds cool, I will try this tomorrow (the rest of the day happens to be one long meeting... oh the joy). All our views implement an interface where the viewmodel is part of it. That should work.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for, thanks a lot :)